# How to store stream of tweets in a single dict?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I wrote a code to get data from twitters streaming api using tweepy.

A small part of the code is given below:

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
           k = [status.author.screen_name.encode('utf-8'),(status.retweeted)]
```

Now this may seem silly, 
k is a list which changes continuously.
How can I store all k's in a single dictionary.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable (a list, though you mentioned wanting a dict), to the class.

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    tweets = []
    def bar(self, status):
        k = [status.author.screen_name.encode('utf-8'),(status.retweeted)]
        self.tweets.append(k)

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar('1')
>>> f.bar('2')
>>> f.bar('3')
>>> f.tweets
[['1', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['3', '3']]
```

[More information on classes can be found here.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Note that "tweets" is a class variable. If you have two instances of listener, they share the same instance of tweets, so adding to one will add to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the help..This works...One more doubt...Is it possible to limit the number of elements in the tweets list?

Comment: @YEDURAGBABU have an `add()` method in the `listener` class that appends items to the list instead of calling `append()` on the list itself. In the method, add code for limiting the size.

Comment: Sorry...but I dint understand that...Can you please explain?

Comment: @YEDURAGBABU like `def bar` in the answer, add another method, called `add`. Instead of calling `self.tweets.append(k)`, call `self.add(k)`.